# Do I need to reinstall apps to take advantage of app thinning?

Tags: storage, ios

I don't notice any difference in app sizes in iOS 9 so I was wondering if app slicing doesn't kick in until next time I update apps or reinstall them?

I realize not all apps will support it, but I have so many that it should have shown a difference anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to re-install or upgrade existing apps to benefit. Apple is unlikely to pro-actively thin apps already installed on iOS devices.

The roll out may also be slowed by bugs and lack of developer support. For example in iOS 9.0, Apple [disabled App Slicing](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=092415a) due to a bug:

> ### App Slicing Currently Unavailable
>
> September 24, 2015
>
> App slicing is currently unavailable for iOS 9 apps due to an issue affecting iCloud backups created from iOS 9 where some apps from the App Store would only restore to the same model of iOS device.
>
> When a customer downloads your iOS 9 app, they will get the Universal version of your app, rather than the variant specific for their device type. TestFlight will continue to deliver variants for your internal testers. **App slicing will be reenabled with a future software update.** No action is needed by you at this time.

Comment: But I'm running 9.0.2: "The issue affecting app slicing has been fixed, and device-specific versions of apps will be delivered when downloaded by users running iOS 9.0.2 or later."